# How can a Linear Chain Conditional Random Field be implemented for a multi-label binary classification problem in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, crf

I'm working on my first machine learning project in Python - using TensorFlow to try and syllabify words using the [Moby Hyphenator II](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/gutbook/lookup?num=3204) dataset.

I have been treating this as a multi-label binary classification problem in which words and their syllables are encoded in the following format:

```py
T e n - s o r - f l o w
0 0 1   0 0 1   0 0 0 0
```

However, this approach has the weakness that it doesn't consider adjacent labels when making a prediction; doing so would most likely improve accuracy as syllable breaks (`1`) are unlikely to be immediately followed by more syllable breaks, which should be taken into account.

I understand that a Linear Chain CRF would be suited to this task - [previous syllabification work](https://github.com/jacobkrantz/lstm-syllabify) has used CRFs to attain high syllabification accuracies ([>98%](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.13362.pdf)) on several datasets, but I am completely unsure as to how I can implement this myself as the only articles I can find are either highly mathematical in nature (no code) or are implementations in different frameworks such as PyTorch. I am currently using a simple `Dense` output layer with a sigmoid activation and threshold of `0.5` to predict a binary string (for example, `01000`), with 1s where the syllable breaks in the input word are believed to be - how do I implement and use a CRF instead?